# GIMP - Image wont move at all

Tags: gimp, images, designers

Tried every, Merge Down, move it, different image, uninstalling. Dont know what else to do.

Heres a little vid.

https://streamable.com/er09oz

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Gimp, but it looks like your image might be locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing your tool options, so this is a guess.

Open the Tool Options using *Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Tool Options*, and make sure it looks like this. The *Move* option should be set to *Layer*, shown highlighted in red below:

[image]